# Dual processor vs single processor for a LAMP server

Tags: multithreading, processor, xeon-phi

I have a question regarding server performance of a dual processor socket server vs a single processor socket server. My two choices are as follows. Assume that the rest like RAM and HD are identical.

```
1 Processor:
Xeon E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz
Socket: LGA2011-v3
Clockspeed: 2.4 GHz
Turbo Speed: 3.2 GHz
No of Cores: 8 (2 logical cores per physical)
```

VS.

```
2 Processors:
Xeon E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz
Socket: LGA1150
Clockspeed: 3.5 GHz
Turbo Speed: 3.9 GHz
No of Cores: 4 (2 logical cores per physical)
```

Combined, the number of cores is the same, so in theory the server performance should be the same right?

The server is a LAMP box with a huge database constantly being queried with select queries.

Answer (score 1):

> Combined, the number of cores is the same, so in theory the server performance should be the same right?

The stats you listed yourself differ, why would you expect the same level of performance?

Most bottlenecks in real-world non-optimized codebases stem from cache misses, so you want a machine with more cpu cache. That's the first one.

Similarly, more than one socket is typically detrimental to performance unless you have a workload which knows how to use them.

But the real question is what kind of traffic is expected here. Perhaps there is 0 reason to go with such a box in the first place. You really want to consult someone versed in the area and not just buy/rent a box because you can.